# How to remap "i" in netrw?

Tags: key-bindings

I remapped my hjkl keys to ijkl, but in netrw, "i" switches view styles.

How to change this? Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want your cursor to move left when pressing `i` in the built-in file browser netrw, then try adding the following code in your `$MYVIMRC` file :

```
augroup netrw_mapping
    autocmd!
    autocmd filetype netrw call NetrwMapping()
augroup END

function! NetrwMapping()
    noremap <buffer> i h
endfunction
```

The reason why your custom mapping didn't have the expected result, is probably because netrw set up mappings that are local to the buffer (using the `<buffer>` option), which means they override your global mappings.

The previous code adds an autocommand that automatically calls a function whenever you enter a buffer whose filetype is netrw. The function then sets up your mapping using the `<buffer>` option, which means it should be able to override the local mapping previously done by netrw.

I found the workaround from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42939/125618).

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution is to put your config in `.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim`:

```
noremap <buffer> i h
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I added that file with those contents, but there was no change. It's a bummer because I would have preferred this solution.