# Trouble remapping netrw

Tags: key-bindings, netrw

I'm using a bépo keyboard, kind of like a dvorak keyboard but for french. One of the most important aspect of using a bépo layout with vim is that I have to `hjkl` <-> `ctsr`. To do so I have this in my `.vimrc` :

```
" [HJKL] <-> {CTSR}
noremap c h
noremap C H
noremap t j
noremap T J
noremap s k
noremap S K
noremap r l
noremap R L

noremap h c
noremap H C
noremap j t
noremap J T
noremap k s
noremap K S
noremap l r
noremap L R
```

Right now I'm trying to use netrw, which ignored my mappings at first but I found the solution [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/how-to-remap-i-in-netrw/5532) and edited `.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` by copy-pasting what's above but with `<buffer>` after each `noremap`. It worked well but I wanted to remap "go up in directory" (currently mapped to `-`) to `c` (that is, `h` for `hjkl`) and "enter directory/edit file" (currently mapped to `\<CR\>`) to `r` (that is, l for `hjkl`). So I added this in my `netrw.vim` :

```
nmap <buffer> c -^
nmap <buffer> r <CR>
```

(I tried with `noremap` first but it didn't work and I can't wrap my head around this)

The remappings worked but... there's only a slight problem: there's a delay for `c`. I believe the reason is because the following mappings exist in netrw: `cb` and `cB`. I tried to unmap those but failed, and tried a few other things but I have a poor mastery of remappings and I am completely stuck.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Not really sure whether this would solve your specific problem, but make sure to check out the [vim-bepo](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-bepo-hard-things) plug-in for better Bépo support in Vim!

Comment: @filbranden Hi! Unfortunaly the very-few plugins for bépo support are often at the state of draft and reflect the tastes/choices of their creators, which often differ from mines... but thanks

Comment: Perhaps a keymap or langmap would be better for using a different keyboard layout?